# Java Calendar issues setting 12pm

Tags: java, calendar

I'm creating a `Calendar` instance (current time) then setting hour minute and am/pm

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

now.set(Calendar.HOUR,12);
now.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
now.set(Calendar.AM_PM,1);
```

Then if I try to grab the am/pm from the now Calendar instance it incorrectly always set to am and 1 day ahead of now. This only seems to happen with hour 12 and no other hour. What is the issue here? Does the order I set them matter or in the case of hour 12, should I use the 24 hour format to set the 'now' instance?
Yes I should have mentioned, this is on Android.

Comment: If you are not on Android, switch to JodaTime and never look back.  java.util.Calendar is one of the worst packages I've ever used.

Comment: Try using 24 hr format, and go with HOUR_OF_DAY

Comment: Which JVM are you using?

Comment: @Jigar. Not worst, just one of the worst. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's because each half of the day goes from hour zero to the end of hour 11. Mathematically speaking, there is no 12th hour (even though we use it all the time in real life). So what you mean to set is hour zero in the PM period, so:

```
    now.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    now.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    now.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
```

By setting the hour to 12, you tell the calendar (right or wrong, you'll have to ask the Oracle engineers) to set it to the 12th hour of the PM period, which winds up being the zero hour of the AM period of the next day.

There are only 12 hours in a half-day period and that count is zero based, so mathematically speaking, there is no 12th hour. It's zero. It is a little counter intuitive because we are used to saying it's 12:30, not 0:30.

Comment: hmmmm your explanation makes sense even though as you say its counter intuitive. I'll give it a go...

Comment: You could set it to 11 AM and then add 1 hour to it, although I don't know if that's better or worse in terms of intuitiveness. :)

Comment: I'm actually not sure if this is true. It kinda makes sense but how come all the other hours (1-11) aren't affected? I only get this issue 12...

Comment: Well, for any hour in the range 0-11, you won't have a problem. But if you set the hour to, say `now.set(Calendar.HOUR,14)`, then it will inevitably move to the next day at 2am. What's counter intuitive is how we tell time in natural language (12:30) when we really mean 0:30pm. Or 14:00pm in my example, is really 02:00am (next day). It makes perfect sense actually.

Comment: Saved the day. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Much better answer for me was by AndroidDev

[How to set time to 24 hour format in Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980899/how-to-set-time-to-24-hour-format-in-calendar)
S/he says
use Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY 
so it should be now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

For 12 AM.

```
LocalTime.MIN.with ( ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM , 12 )
         .with ( ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY , 0 );
```

For 12 PM.

```
LocalTime.MIN.with ( ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM , 12 )
             .with ( ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY , 1 );
```

[Try it live](http://ideone.com/lpWOSj).

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by java.time in Java 8 and later, and in Android supplanted by the [adaptation](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) of the [java.time back-port](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

## `LocalTime`

Whenever possible, use 24-hour time as you mention in your Question. The `LocalTime` class in java.time does this, using hours 0-23 for hour-of-day.

If forced to use 12-hour clock, one approach is to construct strings and then let `LocalTime` parse them.

```
String input = hour + ":" + minute + " " + ( isAM ? "AM" : "PM" ) ;  // Ex: 7:53 AM
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a formatting pattern to match with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "h:m a" );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input , f );
```

If all you need is time-of-day, you are done.

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you need to associate this time with a date, create a `LocalDate` object, specify the context of your intended time zone with a `ZoneId`, and shake to mix into a `ZonedDateTime`. If your time-of-day is invalid for that date, java.time makes an adjustment as needed. Be sure to study the JavaDoc to understand the behavior of such an adjustment to see if you agree.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 4 );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z );
```

## `TemporalField`

The [`TemporalField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalField.html) interface provides for classes that can alter date-time values. Because java.time uses [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), we instantiate an fresh object based on another object but with a particular field altered. The [`ChronoField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) enum provides some handy implementations of this interface.

The [`HOUR_OF_AMPM`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#HOUR_OF_AMPM) object lets us specify the hour-of-day counting 1-12 rather than 0-23. Combine this with [`AMPM_OF_DAY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#AMPM_OF_DAY) to specify if that 1-12 hour was meant for the morning (AM = 0) or the evening (PM = 1). You can chain these calls for convenience.

Let's try both AM and PM, passing either a zero or a one in that last argument. First AM, passing a `0`.

```
LocalTime fiveAm = 
    LocalTime.MIN.with ( ChronoField.HOUR_OF_AMPM , 5 )
                 .withMinute ( 23 )
                 .with ( ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY , 0 );  // 05:23
```

And PM, passing a `1`.

```
LocalTime fivePm = 
    LocalTime.MIN.with ( ChronoField.HOUR_OF_AMPM , 5 )
                 .withMinute ( 23 )
                 .with ( ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY , 1 );  // 17:23
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "fiveAm.toString(): " + fiveAm );
System.out.println ( "fivePm.toString(): " + fivePm );
```

> fiveAm.toString(): 05:23
>
> fivePm.toString(): 17:23

That code above uses `HOUR_OF_AMPM` which counts hours 0-11. Let's try a zero to see the effect.

```
LocalTime zeroAm = 
    LocalTime.MIN.with ( ChronoField.HOUR_OF_AMPM , 0 )
                 .withMinute ( 23 )
                 .with ( ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY , 0 );

LocalTime zeroPm = 
    LocalTime.MIN.with ( ChronoField.HOUR_OF_AMPM , 0 )
                 .withMinute ( 23 )
                 .with ( ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY , 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "zeroAm.toString(): " + zeroAm );
System.out.println ( "zeroPm.toString(): " + zeroPm );
```

> zeroAm.toString(): 00:23
>
> zeroPm.toString(): 12:23

But the Question wants to use `12`, meaning we count hours of the 12-hour clock as 1-12 rather than 0-11. The java.time classes accommodate that as well. Just switch from using `HOUR_OF_AMPM` to [`CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM).

```
LocalTime twelveAm = 
    LocalTime.MIN.with ( ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM , 12 )
                 .withMinute ( 23 )
                 .with ( ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY , 0 );

LocalTime twelvePm = 
    LocalTime.MIN.with ( ChronoField.CLOCK_HOUR_OF_AMPM , 12 )
                 .withMinute ( 23 )
                 .with ( ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY , 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "twelveAm.toString(): " + twelveAm );
System.out.println ( "twelvePm.toString(): " + twelvePm );
```

> twelveAm.toString(): 00:23
>
> twelvePm.toString(): 12:23

Again, I advise you to **use 24-hour clock whenever possible**. Makes life much easier, works by default with `LocalTime` class, and avoids the mistakes and confusion that comes from the ambiguity of 12-hour clock.

## Live code

You can see all that [example code running live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/lpWOSj).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).